# Change package name in android

Tags: android, google-maps, package-name

How to change Package name from com.example.abc to com.test.abc . And i am also using google maps so i have to make what changes there?

I have tried refactor option , chnaging the package name from manifest .

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse: Use refactor and clean your project.

Comment: I amusing Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to change the package name(Eclipse)

1. Right click on project
2. Go to Android tools
3. Click on Rename Application package

Change the package in displayed popup.

For Map You have to log-in to Google API again and you have to generate new Key With changed package name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your **Google API Console**, then on the `Credentials` section under `API & AUTHENTICATION` and add the new package with the hash value.

```
...90:04:30:40:EE:...;com.test.abc
```

if you don't make this change your app wont be allowed to show any Google map nor use it´s functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your 
package name > Refractor > Rename > select all checkboxes > click on preview button >click ok button

sometime during refraction refractor failed to rename the packagename from manifest file so change it manually normally it never happens but sometime it happens so only in manifest file do this changes manually